# Select only the values that have one or more specific value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table called `CampaingControl`:

```
+----------------+-----+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+
| id_vehicleCamp | vin | id_campaign | id_workorder | id_client | status |
+----------------+-----+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+
|                |     |             |              |           |        |
+----------------+-----+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+
|                |     |             |              |           |        |
+----------------+-----+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+
```

The `status` column have only two values **APPLIED** or **PENDING**.

What i need to do is show all the `distinct` values ​​in the column `id_campaign` having one or more `status` values ​​equals to **PENDING**.

For example, i have this data in the table:

```
+----------------+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
| id_vehicleCamp |  vin  | id_campaign | id_workorder | id_client |  status |
+----------------+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|        1       | 43006 |      1      |   OT-001-16  |    NULL   | PENDING |
+----------------+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|        2       | 43010 |      1      |   OT-002-16  |     2     | PENDING |
+----------------+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|        3       | 43009 |      1      |   OT-002-16  |    NULL   | APPLIED |
+----------------+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|        4       | 43008 |      2      |   OT-002-16  |    NULL   | APPLIED |
+----------------+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|        5       | 43002 |      3      |   OT-005-16  |     4     | PENDING |
+----------------+-------+-------------+--------------+-----------+---------+
```

The final output needs to be:

```
+-------------------+
| Pending Campaings |
+-------------------+
|         1         |
+-------------------+
|         3         |
+-------------------+
```

The campaing with value `1` have one **APPLIED** `status`, but have `2` with **PENDING** `status`, then isn't completed.

The campaing with value `3` only have one record and have **PENDING** `status`, then isn't completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id_campaign
FROM CampaingControl
GROUP BY id_campaign
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'PENDING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
```

Note that this query will generalize to other questions you might have, such as how many campaigns have *two* pending entries but only one applied entry.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id_campaign AS [Pending Campaings] FROM CampaingControl
WHERE status = 'PENDING' GROUP BY id_campaign HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_campaign AS [Pending Campaings] FROM CampaingControl
WHERE status = 'PENDING'
```

Comment: Thanks for your support the both queries works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It should also work:

```
SELECT id_campaign FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE status = 'PENDING' GROUP BY  id_campaign
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy :

`SELECT id_vehicleCamp
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE id_vehicleCamp = ANY
(SELECT id_vehicleCamp
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE status = 'PENDING')`

Answer (score -1):

you can use the query as,

```
SELECT id_vehicleCamp FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id_vehicleCamp IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT STATUS FROM TABLE_NAME);
```

This query provides your result.